# Ruby on Rails .gsub regex and render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a series of some strings, that i want to convert to render-partial.

For example. I have a @post.content, which contains

> Lopem ipsum dolor sic amet
>   *form_34e141443439d1000000*
>   Lorem dolorem *form_f97391de6275724201000000*

Which i want to process.

I tried

```
content.gsub(/\*form_(.*?)\*/, render(partial: 'forms/render_form', object: CustomForm.where(_id: '\1').first, as: 'form_item'))
```

But that does not do anything correct, results only in "undefined local variable or method `form_item' for #<#:0xb53a2810>" error.

But if i try

```
content.gsub(/\*form_(.*?)\*/, render(partial: 'forms/render_form', object: '\1', as: 'form_item'))
```

and try <%= form_item %> in partial, it returns to me an correct value - f97391de6275724201000000

and if i try

```
content.gsub(/\*form_(.*?)\*/, render(partial: 'forms/render_form', object: CustomForm.where(_id: 'f97391de6275724201000000').first, as: 'form_item'))
```

it works just like i want it to - gets me a form model to process.

QUESTION:

How do i throw \1 value from /*form_(.*?)*/ regexp to CustomForm.where(_id: '\1').first ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the block form of the `gsub` method where the pattern match is available as the `$1` variable:

```
content.gsub(/\*form_(.*?)\*/) do |match|
  render(partial: 'forms/render_form', 
         object: CustomForm.where(_id: $1).first, as: 'form_item'))
end
```